# How to make Windows Services state to "Manual"?

Tags: c++, windows, service

I'm stopping a windows service currently from my code as shown below:

```
srvc_status = ControlService(serviceHandle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, (LPSERVICE_STATUS)&status);
```

But it is changing the state of service to **Automatic (Delayed Start)**. But I need it to be set to **Manual**. I went through the windows documentation also regarding **ChangeServiceConfig** and didn't found anything which says about the options to explicitly set the state to **Manual**. 
Can anyone guide me here towards the correct API call ?

Comment: Not one hundred percent sure this is the answer, but after you stop the service, I think you do need to call `ChangeServiceConfig` but for the `dwStartType` parameter you need to put `SERVICE_DEMAND_START`. So something like this: `ChangeServiceConfig(serviceHandle, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`. Do let me know if it works and I can convert this to an answer.

You'll notice the `dwStartType` enums are related to startup types based on the documentation, hence why I believe `SERVICE_DEMAND_START` is what you need.

Comment: Exactly I also thought of it earlier but wandered into other things on google. It works perfectly fine. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *start type* of a Service can be set via [ChangeServiceConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681987(v=vs.85).aspx). Setting the `dwStartType` parameter to `SERVICE_DEMAND_START` will change it to *Manual* for you.

Here's an example that changes nothing else but the start type: `ChangeServiceConfig(serviceHandle, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

It's not clear at first glance, but you'll notice the `SERVICE_DEMAND_START` enum description says:

> when a process calls the StartService function

For the **process** to call StartService, that can imply something is starting it manually.